# I can't run php artisan migrate inside container pointing out ip external

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, lumen

.env Lumen 6x-

```
DB_HOST=172.17.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=teste
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=teste
```

After run `php artisan migrate` I am getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.**2**' (using password: NO)

I reported this:**172.17.0.1**,  but he used this: **172.17.0.2**.

When it runs inside the container `mysql -h 172.17.0.1 -u root -p` **it works**

I have my server running `apache` and `mysql`. I installed the docker and created a container. But I can't access my database with `php artisan migrate`.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the config cache? `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: It is not cache, because when I put something else, the error is different.

Comment: Yeah but it's not using the password from your `.env`